# Golang: is a mutex required for a package-scoped variable with read-only access?

Tags: go

If I have a package-scoped variable like this:

```
var (
    bus *Bus // THIS VARIABLE
)

// Bus represents a repository bus. This contains all of the repositories.
type Bus struct {
    UserRepository *UserRepository
    // ...
}
```

...and I give access to the `bus` variable on my repositories so that they can access each other, do I need to use any sort of mutex if they can be used concurrently?

Quick pseudocode of what would happen:

```
// Router
router.GET("/user/:id", c.FindUser)

// Controller
func (c *UserController) FindUser(w http.ResponesWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte(c.UserService.FindUser(r.Get("id"))))
}

// Service
func (s UserService) FindUser(id int) *domain.User {
    return s.UserRepository.FindByID(id) 
}

// Repository
func (r UserRepository) FindByID(id int) *domain.User {
    // This is where the package-scope `bus` variable will be used
}
```

In the `FindByID` function, I may use the package-scoped `bus` variable, which of course can be accessed concurrently since it will be called whenever an HTTP request triggers it, and those are all handled concurrently.

Comment: You can have multiple goroutines read from a value, but how do you use it for anything is it's never written? The rule is simple, you need synchronization if there are concurrent writes, or concurrent reads and writes for _any_ value.

Comment: I use an SQL driver to do actual writing. But the `bus` variable is essentially a factory full of methods that are wrappers over the actual SQL implementations, and the SQL driver handles it's own concurrency rules so I don't have to worry about that.

Comment: If all you are doing is reading and writing from a DB, then no, you won't need a mutex. But if any of the internal variables are written to in the process, then they (or the whole bus) will need to be locked. For example, if you happened to have an internal counter for how many reads are done through the bus, then that would need a mutex.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear what if package variable is an pointer like `var catList []*model.Cat` then inside other function, i use gorm to fill data, `catList, _ = model.Cat{}.All()`
does it need to be locked?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If all you do is reading the content of variable - then no, you do not need mutex. However, if you ever mutate its state, then you need to protect it.

Two concurrent writes or concurrent write and read can cause problems. If your writes are rare, you might want to use [RWMutex](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#RWMutex). It will allow multiple readers to access, but not together with a writer.

Also, check out [race detector](https://blog.golang.org/race-detector). It is best effort detector, so it does not guarantee that you do not have race condition, but it can detect some use cases. Also note that you need to cause race in order for race detector to detect it, so writing tests that use your `bus` concurrently or simulating real conditions has to be done.